Looking for a library with basic EtherCAT master functionality
I have a P1AM-200 PLC with P1AM-ETH Arduino compatible Ethernet Shield based on the Wiznet W5500 Ethernet Controller. I'm looking for a library with basic EtherCAT master functionality, but there is nothing listed in Arduino IDE 2.3.1 Library Manager. I found Easy Master at https://www.bausano.net/en/hardware/easycat.html. Is there anything else known to work available?

You can consider SOEM instead. SOEM is a popular open-source EtherCAT master library written in C. While it is not specifically designed for Arduino, it is highly flexible and might be adapted for your hardware.
